# Handling exceptions in global.asax ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception, global-asax

I have code which is catching all exceptions in Global.asax

```
 protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            System.Exception exc = context.Server.GetLastError();
            var ip = context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            var url = context.Request.Url.ToString();
            var msg = exc.Message.ToString();
            var stack = exc.StackTrace.ToString();
        }
```

How I can get controller name where this error happened

How I can get request client IP?

And can I filter exceptions? I dont need 404, 504.... erors

thanks

Comment: `I dont need 404, 504.... erors` ehh? That's how HTTP works. And what do you mean with `can I filter exceptions`?

Comment: This post will definitely help you http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/5/exception_handling_in_asp_net_mvc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Global.asax has not notion of controllers and actions, so I believe there is no an API for retrieving controller and action names. However you might give a try for resolving request URL:

```
HttpContextBase currentContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
RouteData routeData = urlHelper.RouteCollection.GetRouteData(currentContext);
string action = routeData.Values["action"] as string;
string controller = routeData.Values["controller"] as string;
```

To get the user IP you can use `UserHostAddress` property:

```
string userIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

To filter out HTTP exceptions that you are not going to handle you can use something like:

```
HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;
if (httpException != null)
{
    switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
    {
        case 404:
        case 504:
            return;
    }
}
```

One last remark about exception handling - it is not a best practice to do it at global level when there is a way to perform it more locally. For instance in ASP.NET MVC base `Controller` class has a method:

```
protected virtual void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
```

which, when overridden, will give you full control on the occurred exception. You can have all the info that is available for you in Global.asax **plus** ASP.NET MVC specific features like a reference to controller, view context, route data etc.

Comment: Andrei thank you for replay your code works perfectly. Can you provide some good tutorial about base controller class?

Comment: @Acid, sure. For basic examples check out this [blog post](http://www.entwicklungsgedanken.de/2009/07/16/redirect-from-the-onexception-method-inside-the-controller-with-asp-net-mvc/) and this [article](http://www.devproconnections.com/article/aspnetmvc/aspnet-exception-141263).

Comment: You can skip the using UrlHelper usage (And skip the MVC reference) with...'RouteData routeData = System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(currentContext);'

Answer (score 3):

i used like this it's below

you can get user ip like this

```
var userip = context.Request.UserAgent;
```

and you can get your url where this error happened like this

```
var ururl = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
```

i think this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a different tack and put use an attribute on your controllers (or base controller if you have one)

```
 public class HandleErrorAttributeCustom : HandleErrorAttribute
    {
       public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            //you can get controller by using
            context.Controller.GetType()

            //however, I'd recommend pluggin in Elmah here instead 
            //as it gives this easily and also can has filtering
            //options that you want

        }
}
```