# Access Current Area Name in Session Start - MVC 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

We have multiple areas in our MVC 4.0 application and I am looking for a way to get the current Area name when the session is started.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC - Get Current Area Name in View or Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723689/asp-net-mvc-get-current-area-name-in-view-or-controller)

Comment: We need this on the session start event.

Comment: Have a look at this one then, just use "area" instead of controller/action. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16820248/1241562